# Rewriting "He doesn't study hard, so he can fail the examination."

Tags: sentence-construction, subjunctives, if

Rewrite the following sentence:

> He doesn't study hard, so he can fail the examination.

> If .........

And the answer is:

> If he studied hard, he wouldn't fail the exam.

Can I write the sentence as follows:

> If he studies hard, he won't fail the exam.
> If he studied hard, he wouldn't fail the exam.

Are both sentences correct? Could you give me more information about this grammar point?

Comment: Yes, these are both valid, although subtly different in meaning, and both are good grammar.  The first sentence is worded strangely though - “… so he can fail the exam” suggests that he has avoided study so that he can gain the skill required to fail the exam.  It would be mor usual to say “he could fail”, “he may fail” etc.

Comment: @Frog you can read the *so* as *so that* (with your interpretation), but you can also read it as *therefore*. It's ambiguous - though the comma (and obviously the context) suggests the latter reading.

Comment: @Maciej Stachowski - ‘so he can fail’ isn’t typically used in this way in UK English and so the intended meaning isn’t well defined.  Normally you’d use that construction to show that an action had facilitated something rather than creating risk of something bad happening.